# ls -l command and Password file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, filesystems

when we execute `ls -l` command to list files in directories, Does the `/etc/passwd` file get accessed. Please explain ?? if yes How can I verify it ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. `/etc/passwd` is used to map user IDs to usernames. We can turn this off by using `-n`, which will show us the numeric user IDs and group IDs (uids, gids):

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Sep 30 10:54 bar

$ ls -n
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Sep 30 10:54 bar
```

Ultimate proof:

```
$ strace ls -l 2>&1 | grep /etc/passwd
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4

$ strace ls -n 2>&1 | grep /etc/passwd
# no output
```

Answer (score 2):

I added +1 to Thomas, but I want to note that the file may be accessed, and may be not. It depends on contents of "/etc/nsswitch.conf".

In this case

```
$ grep passwd /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:         compat
```

the file will be accessed, and in this case

```
$ grep passwd /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:         ldap
```

it will not.

Comment: @lgor your explanation was also worth reading .. thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

"ls -l" prints information about files and directories (metadata), e.g.: access rights, size, etc. It does not read contents of any file or directory. Even if you do not have any access to a file you still can read its metadata (e.g.: access rights, size). The same applies to a directory (exception: if you cannot read a drirectory you cannot list it's contents, if you cannot "execute" a directory you cannot use it as a component of a path to access something inside it).

Most modern Linux systems are configured to use "shadow passwords", which means that **/etc/passwd** does not contain password hashes (read: sensitive data). Password hashes are stored in **/etc/shadow**. This is the reason why **/etc/passwd** is readable by everyone (contains only metadata about users: their names, ids, shells, groups, etc.), but **/etc/shadow** is only readable by root.